# How do I install Windows 8 or 10 on MacBook Air 2015 11" El Captain?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, bootcamp, windows

I want to install Windows on my internal SSD. Because my internet connection is slow and unreliable, and the download within Boot Camp Assistant can't be resumed I've downloaded the support software (Boot Camp drivers: AppleBcUpdate.exe) directly from Apple using this [direct link](http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/16/10/031-55711/ufi4c7o3x20i5ge93l2yu869yegn222i8l/AppleBcUpdate.exe).

I did use the Boot Camp Assistant to make a bootable drive for Windows and put the support software in another drive. When I try to proceed I get the error message

```
"couldn't find the support software.....".
```

How can I proceed from here?

Comment: It's difficult to understand this question as it's written. Did you use Bootcamp assistant to make the bootable drive? Did you let Bootcamp assistant download the support software? Please edit the question to explain exactly what you did and we'll see if we can help you solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) We're here to help, but @NoahL is spot on. As it currently reads, your question leaves a lot for us to have to guess. Your reference to a _direct link_ also causes me some concern. Can you please use the _edit_ link below your question to clarify your situation and provide more details.

Comment: It's rather difficult to understand which problem you are facing. Instead of talking about options and potential solutions, can you please rewrite your question to focus on what you are trying to accomplish (installing Windows XY), which specific steps you've already taken (e.g. started the Bootcamp Assistant) and where exactly you are stuck now. This will make it easier to understand the problem and provide answers.

Comment: @patrix the significant problem is 1.

Comment: @ klanomath i have clarified the situation on 2nd paras 1st and 2nd line upto later

Comment: @klanomath has it been verified to work on my macbook model for windows 10 or 8 officially?(the direct link you provided)

Comment: @klanomath i had actually found that before but idk how to use it how do u compile that script in mac any idea?

Comment: I've heavily edited your question, please add back any details which I removed which may be required to understand what's going on until the point you get the error message. @klanomath, feel free to add your comment regarding the download as an answer.

Comment: @klanomath so this direct link's download is the exact same .pkg the default BCA would have downloaded right? and is it the full and final one?

Comment: @klanomath appreciate that.Hope (or does work what u think?) it works.

Comment: @klanomath as you said the brigadier would download the windows support.dmg into the master folder, but the direct link you provided seems different (in .pkg) how did you get that?

Comment: @Anon added Terminal output of the Python script (which contains the direct link to the Apple pkg installer)

Comment: @klanomath so the output below displays the lastest support software for the specified model right? Thanks anyways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You fetched the wrong installer. The recommended way is to simply open in the menubar of Boot Camp Assistant > Action > Download Windows Support Software.

This will download and unpack all necessary files and you can simply continue installing Windows.

---

An alternative is [brigadier](https://github.com/timsutton/brigadier). This is a python script which downloads support software for an arbitrary Mac.

Download the [zip](https://github.com/timsutton/brigadier/archive/master.zip) (direct link!) and unpack it. Open Terminal and cd into the resulting folder: `cd .../Path/to/brigadier-master` (probably `cd ~/Downloads/brigadier-master`).

Then enter `./brigadier --model=MacBookAir7,1`. The command will download the proper installer and compile a WindowsSupport.dmg in the brigadier-master folder. This dmg file contains all necessary files and folders (an xml file, a drivers folder and a $WinPE folder).

Terminal output:

```
host:brigadier-master user$./brigadier --model=MacBookAir7,1
Using Mac model: MacBookAir7,1.

Model supported in package distribution file at http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/39/14/031-55710/u2c6bi4yl91ud1lqc3k53bx9860hvsnf7z/031-55710.English.dist.

Distribution 031-55710 supports the following models: MacBook8,1, MacBookAir5,1,
MacBookAir5,2, MacBookAir6,1, MacBookAir6,2, MacBookAir7,1, 
MacBookAir7,2, MacBookPro9,1, MacBookPro9,2, MacBookPro11,1, MacBookPro11,2,
MacBookPro11,3, MacBookPro11,4, MacBookPro11,5, MacBookPro12,1, MacPro6,1, 
Macmini6,1, Macmini6,2, Macmini7,1, iMac13,1, iMac13,2, iMac13,3, iMac14,1, 
iMac14,2, iMac14,3, iMac14,4, iMac15,1.

Making directory /Users/user/Downloads/brigadier-master/BootCamp-031-55710..

Fetching Boot Camp product at URL http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/39/14/031-55710/u2c6bi4yl91ud1lqc3k53bx9860hvsnf7z/BootCampESD.pkg.

100.0% 1614454784 / 1614454648 bytes
Expanding flat package...

Extracting Payload...

Extracted to /Users/user/Downloads/brigadier-master/BootCamp-031-55710/WindowsSupport.dmg.

Done.
```